# Prove that if f is continuous at c and $f(c)<y$, then $\exists \delta >0$ such that $\forall x \in Dom(f)$ and $x$ \in $(c- \delta , c + \delta)$...

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that if $f$ is continuous at $c$ and $f(c)<y$, then $\exists \delta >0$ such that $\forall x \in Dom(f)$ and $x \in (c- \delta , c + \delta)$ implies $f(x) < y$.

I know that $f$ is continuous at $c$ and $f(c) < y$. So I should choose a $\delta$. But I am not sure how to progress after that.

Comment: Why is there a "..."?  please write the full question.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is continuous at $x = c$ and $y - f(c) > 0$ by continuity of $f$ we have
$$\exists \delta > 0 : x \in (c - \delta, c + \delta) : |f(x) - f(c)| < y - f(c)$$
So for $x \in (c - \delta, c + \delta)$ we have
$$ f(c) - y < f(x) - f(c) < y - f(c) \implies f(x) < y $$
as desired.